# Definition of product measure

Tags: measure-theory

When I was reading this definition of product measure from the text book, it says:
$A\in \mathcal {F= F_1 \times F_2}$ is an arbitrary set, $A=A_1\times A_2$. Then the product measure is defined by $P(A)=P_1(A_1)P_2(A_2)=\int_{\Omega_2} P_1 (A_{\omega_2})dP_2(\omega_2)$

I just wonder how can it directly get that intergal.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker sorry, what is unclear here? The definition or my qustion?

Comment: I am not sur what the question is. You want to know why $P_1(A_1)P_2(A_2)=\int_{\Omega_2} P_1 (A_{\omega_2})dP_2(\omega_2)$?

Comment: yes, i dont know how is that integral come from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is any subset of $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$, $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$, and $\omega_2\in\Omega_2$, we can build the *sections* $$A_{\omega_2}=\{\omega_1'\in\Omega_1:(\omega_1',\omega_2)\in A\}\subseteq\Omega_1$$ 
and $$A_{\omega_1}=\{\omega_2'\in\Omega_2:(\omega_1,\omega_2')\in A\}\subseteq\Omega_2.$$

If $A$ is a rectangle, $A=A_1\times A_2$, then $A_{\omega_2}=A_1$ if $\omega_2\in A_2$ and $A_{\omega_2}=\emptyset$ if $\omega_2\notin A_2$. In particular, the function $P_1(A_\omega)$ takes the value $P_1(A_1)$ on $A_2$ and the value $0$ ouside of $A_2$. Let $1_{A_2}$ be the indicator function of $A_2$ on $\Omega_2$. So we get $$\int_{\Omega_2} P_1 (A_{\omega_2})~dP_2(\omega_2)=\int_{\Omega_2}P_1(A_1) 1_{A_2}~dP(\omega_2)$$
$$=\int_{A_2}P_1(A_1)~dP(\omega_2)=P_1(A_1)P_2(A_2).$$

Comment: Hi, Michael. I have a question regarding the last line. If $P_{1}(A_{1})=\infty$, can we still take it out and get the results?

Comment: @Andrew_Ren The argument still works, but the issue of defining the product measure becomes more complicated when the spaces involved are not $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: The space is still $\sigma$ finite, but not all the measurable sets have finite measure. It seems to me that $Int(a 1_{A}) = a m(A)$ only works when $a$ is finite.

Comment: @Andrew_Ren The usual rules used are that, with $a>0$, $a\cdot\infty=\infty$, $\infty\cdot\infty=\infty$, and  $0\dot\infty=0$. Everything works out.